# How to change date for SQL table (using phpmyadmin)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having trouble understanding how to manipulate the format of dates in SQL.  I created a column and set the type to `date`. The default format seems to be `yyyy-mm-dd`.  I would prefer a format like `Jan 1, 2015`.  Is it best to keep the actual data stored in SQL in the seemingly standard `yyyy-mm-dd` format and convert it from there?

In my case, I want to create select (dropdown) html forms that are based off my SQL date data.  But I'd like the dates to be displayed in the `Jan 1, 2015` format.  So it seems I would need to convert the SQL data into my desired format, and then when submitting back to SQL I would need to re-convert it into the standard format.  For the latter portion, the following code seems to work.  But how do I accomplish the former task of taking `yyyy-mm-dd` and converting it to my preferred format?

```
$myinput='Jan 1, 2015'; 

$sqldate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($myinput)); 

echo $sqldate;
```

Comment: Just to be clear, when you store a date in a date data type, it is not stored in any format. Format is just used to display the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For processing date/time information in PHP, the best way is to use a [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) as exchange format. You can achieve this via [UNIX_TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function. In PHP, you then use [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) or [gmdate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) to format the time as desired. Finally when storing the timestamp back in MySQL, use [FROM__UNIXTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).

Issue the query:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime_column`) AS `unixtime` FROM `table`;
```

In PHP you then format it the way you like:

```
$unixtime = $row['unixtime']; // $row is the row fetched from database
echo gmdate('Y-m-d', $unixtime);
```

You then can manipulate the time:

```
$unixtime += 86400; // add one day
```

Finally, store it back in MySQL:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `datetime_column` = FROM_UNIXTIME($unixtime) WHERE …
```

(You probably use prepared statements or other means of preventing SQL injection.)

Bonus tip: A timestamp or any date/time is useless if you have no idea about the time zone. So the best is if you always store date/time in UTC and then convert it to the time zone you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DATE_FORMAT()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) to convert your date value to your desired format. As for your case:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`your_col_name`,'%b %d, %Y') AS `your_col_name` FROM `tbl_name`
```

On the other hand you can use [STR_TO_DATE()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php) to store different format of
date into database. As for example if you want to store `Jan 1, 2015` into database without convert it to mysql default format, than you can use:

```
UPDATE `tbl_name` SET `date_col_name` =STR_TO_DATE($date_str,`%b %d, %Y`) WHERE {CONDITION}
```

**But less operation in MySQL is suitable for faster query.**

Comment: So as I understand it now, I would use PHP to convert when going into SQL, and I would use SQL to convert when coming back out?

Comment: Thank you.  It seems there are probably several solutions to this by using both SQL or PHP, but your solutions look like they will suit my needs.

Edit: I see, so is there a way to keep this conversion out of my SQL but instead use PHP instead of the UPDATE sql code?